# DeepPavlov installation: AttributeError: module 'collections' has no attribute 'Iterable'

Tags: python-3.x, installation, pip, deeppavlov

I'm trying to install deeppavlov via pip. It downloads some packages, then it goes "Preparing metadata (setup.py)" ... error; There are 48 lines of output.

I found online, "collections.Iterable is deprecated. Replace it with collections.abc.Iterable."

I'm guessing I have to edit some python file, but don't know which.

Any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance

python version is 3.10.6
pip 2.22.1
Windows 10
(with virtual environment)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now DeepPavlov doesn't support both Python 3.10 and Windows, but we are going to provide support in the future. To install DeepPavlov with edited source code to your python environment, clone library and install it in editable mode:

```
git clone https://github.com/deepmipt/DeepPavlov.git
cd DeepPavlov
git checkout <tag you want to use. 1.0.0rc1, for example>
pip install -e .
```

After this commands code from this directory will be used by environment when you use deeppavlov. Any code modification could be done.